# Problems with prettyPhoto iframes in HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, href, prettyphoto

When trying to validate a site that contains prettyPhoto links that open an iFrame I get the following errors on any href that contains **?iframe=true&height=100%**

> Bad value for attribute href on element a: Query component contains a percent sign that is not followed by two hexadecimal digits.
>
> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

I tried replacing the & with & in the database the hrefs are stored in and even the % with %, but that didn't satisfy the validator, either. I then tried &amp; and &#37; which showed the href correctly as ?iframe=true&height=100% but it didn't influence the size of the iframe anymore.

Is there a way to solve this or do I just have to accept there are 15 errors, as long as the iframes do work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two layers here.

1. A percent sign has special meaning in a URL, so it must be escaped with `%25`.
2. If you are inserting this value into a tag as HTML, you must use `&amp;` for ampersand. If on the other hand, you are doing this with Javascript (e.g. `element.setAttribute('href', 'foo?bar1&bar2')`), then you don't need this.

Comment: Thank you so very much, %25 was just the thing needed and then I realized that I had changed the &amp; back to check both problems separately... Now my page is free of errors! :)